# R - Input value into next row in column

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
V1    V2
10    5
11    15
12    NA
13    NA
```

V1 is an already generated vector found in the external file.  V2 is the column that will get updated and changed.  This dataframe is stored in an external file that gets read-in when the R script is called.  The R script also has an equation that will generate a new value. Code to generate new value:

```
value <- 10 + 4
```

It's a simple addition that will generate the new value.  That value will need to get passed into the V2 column replacing the next row (the 1st NA you see) and then written to the file.  Let's say the R generated value is 14, it should look like this:

```
V1    V2
10    5
11    15
12    14
13    NA
```

I'm having trouble setting up the loop or function in R I need to call in order to accomplish this task.  Any help is appreciated.  Thank you.

Comment: What equation generates that new value? What are the inputs? Is it the previous value in `V2`? How is the new value stored? What is the purpose of `V1`? So many questions... Please at least show some code you used to generate the new value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need to get the position of NA with `which` (to select the first NA element) wrapped on the logical vector derived from `is.na` and do the assignment

```
df$V2[which(is.na(df$V2))[1]] <- value
```

Comment: I know R isn't that strong with loops so is this the preferred method or is it insignificantly different since we are dealing with a small data-set?

Comment: @statsguy  It is vectorized so you don't need to check with each element using a `for` loop and should be faster and efficient for small or big datasets (that can be stored in the memory - the efficiency becomes noticeable)

Answer (score 1):

Use the **match** function

```
df = read.table(text='V1    V2
                      10    5
                      11    15
                      12    NA
                      13    NA',header = T) 

for (i in 4:5) {
  value = 10 + i
  df$V2[match(NA,df$V2)] = value
  print(df$V2)
}
#[1]  5 15 14 NA
#[1]  5 15 14 15
```